# How to conduct db schema migration in sorm?

Tags: migration, schema, sorm

Let's say that I would like to update db columns from

```
case class Link(url:String, auther: String)
```

to

```
case class Link(url:String, auther: String, created: DateTime)
```

However, I don't want to drop the table and create it again with `DropAllCreate`, because I would like to preserve my data.

How are we supposed to do it in SORM? or the only way is to do manual migration with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Manual altering is the only way.